# How to change default location of pip.ini file on Windows 7 system?

Tags: python, windows-7, pip, configuration-files

How do I change the default location of my pip.ini file on my windows system. I know the default is %APPDATA%/pip/pip.ini but at work, that directory of often cleaned out and it is deleted. I saw that you could change the location using PIP_CONFIG_FILE but when I set it, its not working

Comment: take a look here : https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/1.4/configuration.html